# ggplot geom point, modify text

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I am trying to perform pca analysis using R stat module prcomp and ggplot2, sample data looks like below. for each car model there is data in three columns so far i was  able to generate the plot using code given below.

## df:

```
> head(car.df)
   honda_1_smp honda_2_smp honda_3_smp audi_1_smp audi_2_smp audi_3_smp merc_1_smp merc_2_smp
s1    0.000289    0.000000    0.076095   0.056965   0.030314   0.000000   0.000000   0.028548
s2    1.588724    1.678821    0.795915   0.552910   0.503845   0.248782   0.201806   2.324172
s3    0.067802    0.068452    0.082904   0.014259   0.038896   0.044144   0.003634   0.167235
s4    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.008724   0.000000   0.000000
s5    0.822612    1.137569    0.008302   0.025600   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
s6    0.025091    0.096847    0.000000   0.031416   0.024999   0.000000   0.012987   0.000000
```

## Code:

```
carpca = prcomp(t(car.df), center=T)
summary(carpca)
car12 = data.frame(PC1=carpca$x[,1], PC2= carpca$x[,2], type=rownames(carpca$x))
ggplot(car12, aes(x=PC1 , y=PC2 , col=type)) +
  geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = type), hjust=0, vjust=0) +
  xlab("PC1 89%") + ylab("PC2 77%") + ggtitle("car")
```

## plot[image]

## Question

How to group all my replicate headers as one color and shape in the plot and the legend. 
Meaning : Each Honda will have a same color and shape similarly for audi and merc.

Comment: I believe, in `car12`, create another column `brand` indicating brands, then use `color = brand, shape = brand` in `aes` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use regex (gsub) to get rid of the replicate id from the "type" attribute.

```
car12 = data.frame(PC1=carpca$x[,1], PC2= carpca$x[,2], type=gsub("_.*$", "", rownames(carpca$x)))
ggplot(car12, aes(x=PC1 , y=PC2 , col=type)) +
  geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label = type), hjust=0, vjust=0) +
  xlab("PC1 89%") + ylab("PC2 77%") + ggtitle("car")
```

[image]

Comment: It worked like charm, how can I change the shape of each type

Comment: Maybe you could plot your data this way... `ggplot(car12, aes(x=PC1 , y=PC2 , col=type)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = type)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = car12$PC1, y = car12$PC2, 
           label = car12$type, hjust = -0.1, vjust = -0.1) +
  xlab("PC1 89%") + ylab("PC2 77%") + ggtitle("car") 

`

Comment: That worked, except my original data has more than 6 variable and i get the error `Warning messages:
1: The shape palette can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values because more
than 6 becomes difficult to discriminate; you have 7. Consider specifying
shapes manually if you must have them`

Comment: I fixed it using this `scale_shape_manual(values = c(4,8,15,16,17,18,21))`